# Sharp Infrared sensor-Filtering supply ripple

Tags: infrared

I am using Pololu's sharp infrared sensor board  part# GP2Y0A60SZLF and I am trying to minimize the noise caused by the sensor on the voltage supply as much as possible.

I have made a filter and voltage regulator circuit  as shown below,
The IR sensor and the filter PCB are directly connected together. The output is carried out via a wire  7" long from the filter circuit as shown to a main PCB that has another RC filter (R2,C10)
[image: filter schematic]
Here is the scope shot at the 6-12v supply terminal. The spikes below are 1khz, 46mv p-p.
[image: Scope Probe VDD]

What do you suggest to clean the supply line below?

I am also including the waveform on the sensor output.

[image: Sensor Output]

Comment: Normally I would have a really had time caring about 46mVpp of noise on the input of a regulator. Does it actually make its way to the output? Is it really a problem, or are you trying to minimize it to minimize it?

Comment: Hi Matt, it does make it's way to the output and that's one problem. I am planning to build 12 of these feeding off from the same supply line. Right now I can only turn on one at a time because of the noise I would get on the supply line. If I can manage to clean out the supply line  as much as possible then I can turn on all sensors at the same time.

Comment: In your schematic you say "scope probe sensor VDD", but isn't your sensor VDD really at C8? What does the voltage look like there?

Comment: @DigitalNinja What matters to me is the effect of the sensor on the power line which is the input of the regulator. I will have to check  the scope output at C8.

Comment: Okay, I thought you were worried about it the other way around (the input power affecting the sensor output) - which is what I think would be a normal concern.

Comment: So you're saying the input voltage ripple gets worse with additional sensors, and to clarify, your input voltage ripple disappears when the sensor is absent?

Comment: @DigitalNinja that's right, it gets worse with multiple sensors. and no ripple when I disable the sensor.

Comment: @Rocky79 Do you have pin 4 of the sensor connected to ground?

Comment: PIN 4 IS ENABLED (pulled high by default) here is the sensor link
https://www.pololu.com/product/2474

Comment: Sorry I was referencing the sensor data sheet. Are you using the 5V version?

Comment: @DigitalNinja yes, 5v version

Comment: Try and make life easier by measuring the signal as close to the sensor as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sensor draws like 300mA in bursts, likely you can see that on the power.
I have had a similar problem with driving servos, which made huge spikes on the power line when powering from a lab psu.

I suggest to:

- power this all with a battery with small internal resistance, i.e. alkaline AA cells, or LiPo
- increase c3 to at least 470uF or 1000uF
- (might try LC filter on the power lines)

The output signal is not bad with 30mV of noise. Your idea of the RC filters look correct. I'd give also a try with bigger C and smaller R, like R of not more than 1k, and C of some microfarads.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I ended up turning on one sensor at a time rather having them all on ( 12 sensors).  The 30mv noise was acceptable for my application, so it turns out it's not too bad.

Comment: Oh 12 sensors x 300mA! That is quite a load with spikes! Glad you made it working!